# Documentum ERROR ~ IO Exception attempting to acquire interprocess lock

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x, documentum, documentum6.5, dfc

I am getting below exception when trying to fetch a folder content using *DFC API*

```
ERROR ~ IO Exception attempting to acquire interprocess lock

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /bea/documentumCache/cache/6.7.1000.0027/bof/myDocBase/content.lck (No such file or directory)
```

Do you have any idea why this is happening and how can we resolve the same issue?

Note : We are using the *Weblogic server* having *Documentum* setup in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem Statement**

I was getting below exception in my Documentum code (DFC) yesterday

ERROR ~ IO Exception attempting to acquire interprocess lock

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /bea/documentumCache/cache/6.7.1000.0027/bof/myDocBase/content.lck (No such file or directory)

I was able to login successfully on Documentum but the above problem comes when I was trying to fetch a folder’s content like below

IDfFolder folder = session.getFolderByPath(folderPath);

**Reason :** 
Luckily found out the reason after discussing it with server team , we found out that a the 
folder "/bea/documentumCache/cache/6.7.1000.0027/bof/myDocBase" was recently being deleted by the server team. And somehow it was not created again by documentum/weblogic.

**Solution :**
 Like Always once we knew the reason the solution was very easy , we restarted the weblogic server and I believe weblogic/documentum created all those needed folders again. Now I am able to fetch the contents of my folder and do other operations like workflow e.t.c. without any problem.

**Note :**
 Exceptions like this may waste a significant amount of our time to find out the solution while others may have already faced the same problem and their knowledge can be used and solution can be applied in no time.

To the stckoverflow Admins , I couldn't find a related question at your website therefore had to make a question and answer it myself :) , please let me know if you think there is a better way of doing it I will be happy to contribute to this wonderfull community based on your recomendations.